# How to find which region a snapshot is in using aws-cli?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

How can I find out which region an EBS snapshot is in using the aws cli tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... you can't, and you don't actually need to find out the Region, since you already know it.

Confused? Let me explain...

EBS Snapshots exist in a Region. But the only way to obtain information about a Snapshot is to connect to a Region and make an API call to [describe](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ApiReference-query-DescribeSnapshots.html) the Snapshot (or use the Command Line Interface to make the API call for you).

API calls are made to an [Endpoint](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html), which is a URL that 'points' to a Region.

So... To describe a Snapshot, you first connect to the Region, then ask for details about the Snapshot. It won't tell you the Region in which the Snapshot is located, but you already know the Region since you had to select a Region when making the API call.

So... you can't, but you already know it!